# K8s PodsharedInformer, Getting crashloopbackoff count

Tags: go, kubernetes

Getting crashloopbackoff count k8s client - sharedinformer

As the pod starts running again, the crashloopbackoff count becomes 0. Either the pod infomation received onUpdate event doesn't have previous containerstatuses in it or i may be doing something wrong.

If anyone can help me out, it would be great!
thank you

This is what i have done:

```
podInformer.AddEventHandler(
        &cache.ResourceEventHandlerFuncs{
            AddFunc:    onAdd,
            DeleteFunc: onDelete,
            UpdateFunc: onUpdate,
        })

-----------------------------------------------------

const (
    CrashLoopBackOff = "CrashLoopBackOff"
)

func ..(Pod v1.Pod){

ContainerStatuses := Pod.Status.ContainerStatuses

var crashloopbackoff int

for i := range ContainerStatuses {
if ContainerStatuses[i].State.Waiting != nil && ContainerStatuses[i].State.Waiting.Reason == CrashLoopBackOff {
    crashloopbackoff++
  }
}

.....
```